# How change audio volumes with amix filter in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have command to mix two mp3

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2 -c:a libfdk_aac output.mp4
```

How to change volume of every audios in result output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the [volume](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=0.5[a0]; \
 [1:a]volume=6dB[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]amix[a]"
-map "[a]" -c:a output.m4a
```

Comment: why do you recommend amerg then amix?

Comment: @SunghoMoon I've forgotten. It's been a long time. Should have provided an explanation. Use whatever one you prefer. I'll update the answer.

Comment: how about using `amix=weights=` instead of `volume=`?